# How to send bold text on telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telepot

I everyone,
I am using telepot to send text and image on my telegram bot. Below an example of my code:

```
bot.sendPhoto('@XXXXXXXXXX', getImage(soup),
              caption = getTitle(soup) + getDealPrice(soup) , disable_notification=True)
```

getTitle(soup) and getDealPrice(soup) return a string.

How can I bold only getTitle(soup) ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved.

```
bot.sendPhoto(
'@XXXXXXXXXX', 
getImage(soup),
parse_mode='Markdown',
caption = '*' + getTitle(soup)+ '*' + '*' + getDealPrice(soup) + '*',
disable_notification=True
```

)

Thanks

> mo1ein

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/telepot.html#Bot.sendPhoto), use `parse_mode`.

```py
bot.sendPhoto(
    '@XXXXXXXXXX', 
    getImage(soup),
    parse_mode='Markdown',
    caption = f'*{getTitle(soup)}{getDealPrice(soup)}*',
    disable_notification=True
)
```

Comment: I wrote this code: ` bot.sendPhoto('@xxxx', getImage(soup), parse_mode='Markdown',
                  caption = f'{getTitle(soup)}', disable_notification=True)` but the Title is not bold.

Comment: Bacause you didn't use `*`. This is correct ```f'*{getTitle(soup)}{getDealPrice(soup)}*'```

Comment: In this mode I get an error. However I resolved it ;)